# Unity button script runs when I press a keyboard key not associated with that script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am newbie at Unity and I am having a little weird problem with my app. The program is a numeric screen keyboard that displays the value of the number pressed when it is clicked and sends it to another function when the enter button is pressed (see screenshot 1).

[image: app]

Up to here everything is right, but to give the user the capability to also enter and send numbers with the numeric physical keyboard, the same logic has been applied to the physical numeric keys (see screenshots 2 and 3).

[image: logic implemented for keyboard keys 1]

[image: logic implemented for keyboard keys 2]

The problem is that when I use the physical keyboard after having used the screen keyboard and I press the enter key of the keyboard, it also runs the script attached to the last button clicked on the screen keyboard.

Here is the script attached to the button numbers (screenshot 4).

[image: script attached to button numbers]

Enter button just run the same function as in third screenshot: GetAnswer()

I omitted other parts of the code which I believe (hopefully) are irrelevant.

Summarizing, I tried to have two ways of submitting numbers but when I combine them it doesn't work correctly. Button scripts also run when the Enter keyboard key is pressed however it doesn't when other keyboard keys are pressed.

Comment: welcome to focus :P  the last thing clicked has focus.. therefore enter triggers it again

Comment: in general: Please post your code as text not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out by BugFinder in the comments: Unity UI has a *focus* / selected object.

You can basically imagine it just like a web interface where you can use the tab button to select the different UI elements.

When you hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> while a `UI.Button` is still selected, Unity treats it as submission and the button is *clicked* again.

---

As mentioned in order to resolve this in a single place I would first of all have a central controller that controls the text:

```
// TODO: find a better name
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text displayText;

    public void AppendValue(int value)
    {
        displayText.text += value.ToString();

        // make sure buttons are not selected anymore after clicking
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
    }

    public int GetAndResetValue()
    {
        var value = int.Parse(displayText.text);

        ResetValue();

        return value;
    }

    public void ResetValue()
    {
        displayText.text = string.Empty;

        // make sure also the enter button isn't selected to avoid handling the event twice
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
    }
}
```

This way you only implement and maintain this in a single place

And then you could use this in your buttons

```
public class GetNumber : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Controller controller;

    private int value;

    private void Start()
    {
        value = int.Parse(GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text);
    }

    public void getNumber()
    {
        controller.AppendValue(value);
    } 
}
```

and in your other keyboard based input the same

```
[SerializeField] private Controller controller;

....
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.KeyPad0))
{
    controller.AppendValue(0);
}
....

private void GetAnswer()
{
    var answer = controller.GetAndResetValue;
    
    // do something with answer
}

private void Erase()
{
    controller.ResetValue();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for your tips. Although just adding the sentence "EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null)" to the button's script worked I decided to follow your advices for better clarity and understanding of the code. Aditionally I wanted to know if there is a way of disable completely the "focus" in my app.

Comment: @RubenRuiz I don't think this can be done no - I'm not aware of any related event you could attach a listener to and deselect either unfortunately ... only way would be do do this on a dedicated script once a frame in `LateUpdate` e.g. but that might be a bit overkill